# gVim decreases window size when switching between tabs with/without split when using non-standard font size

Tags: vim

When using gVim, whenever I switch between two tabs where one tab is split vertically and the other is not, the horizontal size of the window is decreased by a small amount (probably one column).
This is really annoying as it forces me to resize the window every few minutes.

The behaviour can be reproduced as follows:

1. start gvim
2. create new tab `:tabnew`
3. split window vertically `Ctrl+W v`
4. switch tags `gt` (--> window size will decrease)

Is this somehow intended behaviour or is it just a bug? Anyway, is there some way to prevent this?

In case it matters: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Xfce, using the vim version from the repos (7.3, Included patches: 1-429).

### Update 1

I followed the [instructions of the FAQ posted by nMontu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563903/2095383) and tracked the issue down to the following line of my `.vimrc`:

```
set guifont=Meslo\ LG\ S\ DZ\ 12
```

Actually the issue is the font size, if I change it to

```
set guifont=Meslo\ LG\ S\ DZ\ 10
```

the problem is gone (leaving me with the problem of a too small font, of course...). It's only the font size, changing the font itself does not solve the problem. For other font sizes != 10 the problem is also there (I tested with sizes 8-14).

### Update 2

I updated vim to version 7.4 and when testing with empty buffers, the problem is gone, even when using a font size != 10. However, as soon as I open files, it is there again :(

Answer (score 2):

Following your steps on Linux Mint doesn't show the error. I've executed one hundred tabpage switches and the there was no change on the window size (`qmgtq` to record a macro, `100@m` to execute it).

Notice that vim 7.3 is quite old, you should try updating it to 7.4. But the error you are experiencing probably isn't a vim bug. You should try to follow follow the procedure described on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.
>
> If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the
>   problem is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in
>   one of your local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the
>   error, you try starting Vim this way:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
> ```
>
> If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
>   the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try:
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).
>
> If the problem does not occur, when only loading your .vimrc file, the
>   error must be caused by a plugin or another runtime file (indent
>   autoload or syntax script). Check the output of the :scriptnames
>   command to see what files have been loaded and for each one try to
>   disable each one by one and see which one triggers the bug. Often
>   files that are loaded by vim, have a simple configuration variable to
>   disable them, but you need to check inside each file separately.

---

**Edit**

Vim's documentation is extremely well-written and very comprehensive. You are likely to find most of the details about Vim there. It also has a great FAQ, which can be viewed directly on Vim through [this nice plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3298).

[Vim-FAQ 31.2](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-31.2) has a list of useful references:

> For more information, read
>
> ```
> 'guifont'
> 'guifontset'
> 'guifontwide'
> font-sizes
> -font
> -boldfont
> -italicfont
> -menufont
> -menufontset
> ```

In special, on [:help font-sizes](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_x11.txt.html#font-sizes):

> Note: All fonts (except for the menu and tooltip) must be of the same
>   size!!! If you don't do this, text will disappear or mess up the
>   display.  Vim does not check the font sizes.  It's the size in screen
>   pixels that must be the same.  Note that some fonts that have the same
>   point size don't have the same pixel size!  Additionally, the
>   positioning of the fonts must be the same (ascent and descent).  You
>   can check this with "xlsfonts -l {fontname}".

I don't know the font you mentioned (`Meslo`), but I would guess it is not mono-spaced.

---

**Edit 2**

> Meslo is mono-spaced

[It is possible that Meslo won't work, similar to what is stated in its FAQ](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font/wiki/Frequently-Answered-Questions):

> Q: Can I use Meslo with ... ?
>
> A: As for ... I don't know (yet). You may have to try it out. I do
>   know however that for the time being there appears to be a problem
>   with **an application called SecureCRT which does not recognise Meslo as
>   a monospaced** font. (see also: issue 2)

And [issue 2](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font/issues/2) seems similar to your problem.

> I'm trying to use Meslo in a terminal app that requires a fixed-width
>   font, but when I choose Meslo, it's claiming the font isn't
>   fixed-width.

You also mentioned that

> and besides I am getting the same issue with other mono-spaced fonts
>   (i.e. 'Monospace') as well.

It is strange that it occurs with common mono-spaced fonts, as this kind of problem would certainly have been reported. If you are sure that it happens with fonts that follow the requirements on the Vim documentation then you should fill a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful (see update). I will also try to update vim (unfortunately I am stuck with ubuntu 12.04 for now :/)

Comment: @luator Glad you figured it out

Comment: Bad news: I tested only with empty buffers yesterday. When I open files, the problem is still there...

Comment: [Meslo](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font) is mono-spaced and besides I am getting the same issue with other mono-spaced fonts (i.e. 'Monospace') as well. So maybe the problem is that I somehow have two different fonts for different things? Are there some parts of the application that are not affected by `guifont` and have to be configured with other commands? Maybe something with `guifontwide`, which is the only other font-option I found? But as I understand the documentation, vim will manage this automatically if it is not set.